# Framework7 geolocation

Tags: vue.js, geolocation, html-framework-7

I'm new using Framework7. I would like to know how to implement some geolocation stuff.

My goal is just to get the device's location so I can send it to the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Geolocation is to be obtained by:

- simple JS in browser ( more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation );
- plugin in Cordova App ( more on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation ).

Framework7 itself isn't a tool for geolocation, but it's open to implement several functions.